# Bash scripting egrep response

Tags: regex, linux, bash, grep

Im trying to isolate only the third option from the query for a script

```sh
size=$(df -h / | egrep -o '[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*)?[A-Za-z]?')
```

Which returns

```sh
30G
2.8G
26G
10
```

Is there a simple way to get the 3rd (if not all responses) isolated to separate variables? My next desperation is to pipe the data to a temp txt file then head/tail it to the desired line

Comment: Can you be more specific about what information you're trying to extract from `df` and what you're trying to do with it? Are you trying to get the third column without `df`'s header? `df -h | awk 'NR > 1 { print $3 }'` will work for that.

Comment: Specifically was trying to extract Avail mem from /dev/root on a rasp pi
```df -h / | awk 'NR==2{print $4}'```
returns the wanted value though, Thanks!

Comment: Please place answers in Answer blocks. Later, you can accept your own Answer. Also see [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/173448)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `--output` to control exactly which columns are printed. That way you don't have to do any extra parsing. This will print just the used column and skip the header row:

```
df --output=used -h / | tail +2
```

If you want to get a particular *line* of output you can use `sed`. This will print the third line of output (the header is the first):

```
df --output=used -h / | sed -n '3p'
```

However, rather than looking for a particular line number it'd be smarter to just ask `df` to status the partition you care about. If that were `/home`, for instance:

```
df --output=used -h /home
```

Comment: I was actually looking for avail memory but i tweaked it to
```bash
df -h / --output=avail
``` 
and it worked perfectly! Thanks